# Using an if statement to check if the values of elements in a numpy array are below an interpolated function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, if-statement, filter

Please keep in mind that I am very new to python. I am trying to filter out data that has a value below a interpolated function, and append other parameters of the same element number to lists. The interpolated function uses the elements of an array as an argument, my goal is to make a for loop that will go through each element of the argument array (call it array A) and test if the returned value is equal to or above another array (call it array B).

My current state is that I can get the for loop running through the argument array ( I have it as "for x in A", where x is the element number), but I come to problems at the if statement. I havent been able to find much help for this, so I currently have it as :

```
if B[x] >= Function(A[x]):
```

This returns the error "only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices", and is highlighting both uses of "_[x]". I am not sure how else to go about "filtering" through all the elements in the B array, google has not been my friend as of late.

My question is this: How can I go through a numpy array and check at every element if it's value, when put through a function, is greater than the value of another array? Desired outcome is that I have lists of matching element numbers to the ones that passed the if statment. ie, if the 7th element passes the test, I will be able to append the 7th element of other arrays into a list. the code that I have so far is this:

```
for x in A:
    if B[x] >= Function(A[x]):
        AF.append(A[x])
        BF.append(B[x])
        CF.append(C[x])
        DF.append(D[x])
        EF.append(E[x])
```

All lists here have been initialized as empty lists, and the arrays that I am appending from are all the same length and have float type values. At the end of this loop I would like to have all of these lists filled with the elements of the arrays of the same x as the ones that pass the if statment.

Comment: Minimal code to set up a reproducible example would help a lot clarifying what you want, alongside the matching expected output.

Comment: what's this `x!?